# Vector operation of addition

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

**According to Law of Chasles, we know that:**

$\vec{AB}+\vec{BC} = \vec{AC}$

However, for this question, it makes me confused about this law:

The question is to **calculate $\vec{AB}-\vec{CD}+\vec{AD}+4\vec{BA}-\vec{BC}$**

So if we calculate this according to the law, the procedure would be following:

- $\vec{AB}+\vec{DC}+\vec{AD}+4\vec{BA}+\vec{CB}$
- $\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}+4\vec{BA}+\vec{CB}$
- $\vec{AB}+4\vec{BA}+\vec{AB}$
- $\vec{AB}$ (because $4\vec{BA}+\vec{AB} = 4\vec{BB} = 0$ )

**However, the right answer is $2\vec{BA}$**, which I obtained using another way of calculation:

- $\vec{AB}+\vec{DC}+\vec{AD}+4\vec{BA}+\vec{CB}$
- $\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}+4\vec{BA}+\vec{CB}$
- $\vec{AB}+4\vec{BA}+\vec{AB}$
- $2\vec{AB}+4\vec{BA}$
- $2\vec{BA}$ (because $2\vec{AB}+4\vec{BA} = 4\vec{BA} - 2\vec{BA}$ )

**So the question here is why the first method is not right?**

Comment: The first one is right down to the last step. I don't mean to be unkind, but I honestly don't know why you've come up with $\vec{AB}$, how you believe the parenthetical explanation is valid, or how the parenthetical explanation actually helps get to the presented answer.

Comment: Oh no worries. I just thought, according to the Chasles' law, that we can connect two vectors "head-to-end" as I showed at the beginning. So I just thought that in this case it will work as well

Comment: Perhaps you were missing the _order of operations_: $4\vec{BA}+\vec{AB}$ means $(4\vec{BA})+\vec{AB}$, not $4(\vec{BA}+\vec{AB})$ as you seemed to think.

Answer (score 2):

If im not mistaken your conclusion is wrong in the last bullet is where it fails. Notice that:
$$\vec{BA}=-\vec{AB}$$

So:
$$4\vec{BA}+\vec{AB} \neq 4\vec{BB}$$

It is nothing but $-3\vec{AB}$. Instead we van calculate and get:
$$\vec{AB}+4\vec{BA}+\vec{AB}=2\vec{AB}-4\vec{AB}=-2\vec{AB}=2\vec{BA}$$

As required.

Comment: Okay. It is clear now to me now. I was just stuck at that step where I cannot really understand why. But I am glad that you provided me a very clear explanation. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

$$\vec{AB}-\vec{CD}+\vec{AD}+4\vec{BA}-\vec{BC}=$$

$$ AB+DC+AD+4BA+CB=$$

$$ AB + ( AD+DC+CB)+4BA=$$

$$AB+AB+4BA=2BA$$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!